# Why are c++ concepts's names in PascalCase?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

This wonders me awhile.

Why are c++ concepts's names not using lower_case like anything else?

What else should I begin switch naming to PascalCase also?

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is purely a matter of opinion

Comment: I encounter more `template<class InputIt>`/`template<typename T>` than `template<class input_it>`/`template<typename t>`... So it is consistent with that usage.

Comment: I am pretty sure *concepts* inherited the convention from how people generally define *template parameters*. Better to ask why *template parameters* are the way they are.

Comment: That's called [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: Nothing forces you to try to follow the style of the standard library code, which isn't consistent anyway.

Comment: Bjarne's book uses `Equality_comparable`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc camelCase <- because it has "humps" in the middle.

Comment: See: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1754r0.pdf
It seems this will be in the C++20 standard, but I don't think it is finalized yet.

Comment: @T.C. Yes I always like Stroustrup_style in my own code. But only in *my own code*. Not in the standard. Stroustrup's books also define an Estd namespace for example. You can easily tell it's not part of the standard (nor will it ever be) because it starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

`std` in-language concepts descend from named requurements described in the standard.  Named requirements where likely written in PascalCase to (a) distinguish them from actual code in the standard, and (b) look like a proper noun when they contain one word, and (c) make it clear they are single things, and the words making up the "sentence" lack meaning on their own, and don't derive meaning from their components (at least in a formal sense) (so RandomAccessIterator is an iterator not because it has Iterator in the name, but because its definition says it is an iterator).

In short, named requirements are in PascalCase, and when implementing them in code as concepts they kept the same pattern and often same names.

Comment: "descend from **non-code concepts** described in the standard" : This is what I'm asking for here. Would you mind show me where to read about this, please?

Comment: The official term for these is "named requirements".

Answer (score -3):

Don't sweat the small stuff, just be consistent in whatever style you or your colleagues decide to use.

Comment: I'd like you to know that it wasn't me.